# Is there any way to align google cloud image's resizing to crop from top

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have getting from public facing image urls like this.

http://lh4.ggpht.com/ID5nDUlKkB_YmWizfCrtCIwbQeqanL6CPAG3T215XaGwjyERnJ0IiPvQwf8rR3-KLgg0qRF2bZBJA0xP_1EYC353jp7TqGQ

and by adding `-wXXX` (width) or `-hXXX` (height) or `-c` (crop)

for example http://lh4.ggpht.com/ID5nDUlKkB_YmWizfCrtCIwbQeqanL6CPAG3T215XaGwjyERnJ0IiPvQwf8rR3-KLgg0qRF2bZBJA0xP_1EYC353jp7TqGQ=-w500-h500-c

but above example always crop from center. is there any to make it to do from top, left, or bottom.

I saw this examples somewhere and can't see any offical docs about it..

but for java, and go programmers google app engine may provide many other advance options. and i am not using either one.. i am in php where only two parameter are provided for size and crop (true/false)

Comment: Why don't you get an image as is, and then change its size (and crop, if necessary) using CSS?

Comment: Its too big... Do you want me load 1920p image in 128p placeholder? Above image is just for example...

Comment: if you add =s200 to the end of the url it'll resize it to 200 on the largest side.

Answer (score 0):

The images are cropped evenly from top and bottom, or from left and right sides, depending on the aspect ratio and specified dimensions.

If you want a different cropping behavior, you will need to implement it outside of Google Cloud Storage (i.e. on your server or in your client).

Comment: Thanks andrei... R u sure about that ... Because i thinks it possible in other languages sdk...

Comment: I don't think it's related to languages at all. There is an Image service available in Java and Python, but it's a different service from Cloud Storage.

Comment: I know.but you may know url genraateed by other languagaes sdk...l

Comment: URLs are the same for all languages. It's an API - it just has a limited number of supported options.